Capturing Entire CAN Frames in CANoe TestCases Using CAPL Language
I am currently developing test cases in CANoe using CAPL Language. My objective is to capture and save the entire CAN Frame as it appears on the trace, rather than just the signal it contains. While I understand how to accomplish this in the Network Node using the on message{} event, I am encountering difficulty implementing this within a TestCase. Specifically, I aim for the test case to execute, retrieve the current value of the CAN Frame, and proceed with the intended testing procedures. Any insights or suggestions on achieving this functionality within a TestCase environment would be greatly appreciated.
I initially attempted to utilize CANoe system variables, but found it cumbersome due to the necessity of creating numerous system variables for each CAN Frame. This approach proved to be inefficient for my requirements.

CANoe's test feature set provides functions like testWaitFor... for waiting for a certain event and functions like testGet... for retrieving data.
In your case, you could use testWaitForMessage to wait until a CAN message is seen on the bus, followed by testGetWaitEventMsgData.
In your question you do not specify, whether you want to act on a certain message or just any message.
Assuming the latter, your code could look like this:
long result;
message * MyMessage

result = testWaitForMessage(10000 /* timeout */);
if(result < 0) {
  return;
}

result = testGetWaitEventMsgData(MyMessage);
if(0 != result) {
  return;
}
// process MyMessage

If you want to work an a certain message type you can use one of the overloads of the aforementioned functions.

im trying to act on certain message using its id , i want to read the full 64 byte can FD frame and process it

@MohamedHamed Should work as described. Simply use testWaitForMessage(msg_id, 10000)

Thanks To @mspiller Answer, I've incorporated his feedback and here's the updated version of my code.
I'm sharing it here to help anyone else who might be looking for a similar solution.
void ProcessMessage(int messageId)
{
    int result;          // Used to store return values from functions.
    message 0 MyMessage; // Used to store Message INFO
    
     result = testWaitForMessage(messageId, 10000);
    if (result < 0)
    {
        // Log error if the message could not be received within the timeout period.
        write("Error: Message 0x%X not received within timeout.", messageId);
    }
    else
    {
        // Log success if the message is received.
        write("Message 0x%X received successfully.", messageId);
    }

    // Attempt to retrieve the message data.
    result = testGetWaitEventMsgData(MyMessage);
    if (result != 0)
    {
        // If there's an error retrieving message data, log an error message.
        write("Error: Failed to retrieve message data.");
    }
    else
    {
        // If data is successfully retrieved, display the message content.
        write("Message DLC = %d", MyMessage.dlc);  
        write("Total Data length = %d", MyMessage.DataLength);

        // Print each byte of the message data.
        write("======================");
        for (int i = 0; i < MyMessage.DataLength; i++)
        {
            write("Data byte %d = 0x%X", i, MyMessage.byte(i));
        }
        write("======================");
    }
}




